# ImportError: No module named skeleton.settings

Tags: django, satchmo

I'm using django 1.8 and satchmo project. But after successful installation of satchmo project when I try to start the server it's showing me this error

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named skeleton.settings`



INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'satchmo_store.shop',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django_comments',
    'registration',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'keyedcache',
    'livesettings',
    'l10n',
    'satchmo_utils.satchmo_thumbnail',
    'satchmo_store.contact',
    'tax',
    'tax.modules.no',
    'tax.modules.area',
    'tax.modules.percent',
    'shipping',
    #'satchmo_store.contact.supplier',
    #'shipping.modules.tiered',
    #'satchmo_ext.newsletter',
    #'satchmo_ext.recentlist',
    'product',
    'product.modules.configurable',
    'product.modules.custom',
    'product.modules.downloadable',
    'product.modules.subscription',
    #'satchmo_ext.product_feeds',
    #'satchmo_ext.brand',
    'payment',
    'payment.modules.dummy',
    #'payment.modules.purchaseorder',
    #'payment.modules.giftcertificate',
    #'satchmo_ext.wishlist',
    #'satchmo_ext.upsell',
    #'satchmo_ext.productratings',
    'satchmo_ext.satchmo_toolbar',
    'satchmo_utils',
    #'shipping.modules.tieredquantity',
    #'satchmo_ext.tieredpricing',
    #'debug_toolbar',
    'app_plugins',
    'simple',
    'store.localsite',
    'skeleton',
)
```

Here I've added to installed apps. Still, it doesn't work. Can you tell me the use of the skeleton?
Also somehow skeleton doesn't compatible with django 1.8.

Comment: did you add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: yes I did. I'll show you

Comment: @Moha369 please check